# GraphQL with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I started working with graphQL recently, I am able to connect it with mongodb but I am getting some challenges in it, Now I am trying to connect it with mongoose but it is not happening.

Can any one please help me with your sample code, how to connect with mongoose.
Thanq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This github example fulfill my needs perfectly.

https://github.com/sayden/graphql-mongodb-example

Answer (score 2):

Here is another very simple example: https://github.com/RisingStack/graphql-server.